# How to force Selenium to ignore ctrl/shift actions made in other application?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a test where many 'click on link' actions are proceed for several minutes. 
The problem lies here:
- during the tests I click many times on different links,
- test run in background, webdriver window has no focus
- I use other app in that time (text or code editor) and when I press shift/ctrl button there Webdriver captures it and opens the link in new window/tab.

The Webdriver perform click+shift (or click+ctrl) action really unexpectedly. My test fails because of this. Webdriver multiplies the windows and tabs and losing the handle/contex after some time.

Is there any way to prevent Webdriver from capturing the ctrl/shift keys pressed in other application?

More info & code sample

The very simple way to trigger this issue... Code in C#:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {        
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("google.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq")).SendKeys("were you naughty or nice this year");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            driver.FindElementByClassName("r").Click();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
```

While the test is running:

- open a Notepad
- press and hold Shift key
- after a while you should notice that Webdriver opens new window
- if you press and hold Ctrl button it opens new tab
- issue occurs also if you minimize the Webdriver window - it still captures the keyboard actions

Comment: As an option you may try to run your tests using some virtual display with restricted key capturing

Comment: Thanks for reply. I known this option, but I can not use it at my current, specific test.

Comment: I have added a code example to clarify the issue.

Comment: Don't have windows here, gonna try it later. One more question: how do you initialize webdriver instance?

Comment: Just standard: IWebDriver driver = new FireFoxrDriver();
Without any tricks, settings or browser profiles.

Comment: I point this issue on official Selenium bugtracker and they told me that there is no solution for this problem. Simply, this kind of test should be executed on separate machine/environment.

Answer (score 0):

When you use modifierkeys (Shift, Ctrl) they are not released automatically: the key stays pressed in the background.

To solve this, you can sent Keys.Null to the application, this will release the modifierkeys.